# Frozen columns in Telerik MVC grid

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

Is there a way to implement frozen columns in Telerik MVC grid?

Thank you in advance,
Dana

Comment: What do you mean for "frozen"?  Disabled columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Telerik Grid for ASP.NET MVC does not support frozen columns.